# IOS User Notification not displayed to user

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to understand actionable notifications (Notifications with text and button(s) - thus allowing user to interact with the notification with more than just a tap). I'm following this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types).

First, requesting user permission,

```
// Log() is my custom logging wrapper.

// Called from application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).
func RequestUserPermission() {
       
    AppDelegate.sUserNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (pGranted: Bool, pError: Error?) in
            
        Log("Completion handler of requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) invoked!")
            
        if(pGranted) {
            Log("Permission granted!")
        } else {
            Log("Permission denied!")
            guard let error = pError else {
                Log("nil value in pError!")
                return;
            }
            Log(String(format: "error = %@", error.localizedDescription))
        }
    }
}
```

Then, registering for remote notification and to obtain a device token,

```
// static let sApp: UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
// static let sUserNotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

// Called from application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).
func RegisterForRemoteNotifications() {
    
    AppDelegate.sApp.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
    // Set the app delegate to be notified.
    AppDelegate.sUserNotificationCenter.delegate = self
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        
    Log(String(format: "error.localizedDescription = %@", error.localizedDescription))
}
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken pDeviceToken: Data) {
        
    // Print the device token as a string.
    Log("pDeviceToken = " + pDeviceToken.hexEncodedString())
}

extension Data {
    
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

Then, the notification categories supported by the app needs to be registered. I'm only looking at one meeting notification with 3 buttons.

```
// static let sAcceptActionID: String = "ACCEPT_ACTION"
// static let sTentativeActionID: String = "TENTATIVE_ACTION"
// static let sDeclineActionID: String = "DECLINE_ACTION"
// static let sMeetingInviteID: String = "MEETING_INVITE"

func RegisterNotificationCategories() {
        
    // Specify the actions (buttons) to a notification
    let meeting_accept: UNNotificationAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: AppDelegate.sAcceptActionID, title: "ACTION")
    let meeting_tentative: UNNotificationAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: AppDelegate.sTentativeActionID, title: "TENTATIVE")
    let meeting_decline: UNNotificationAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: AppDelegate.sDeclineActionID, title: "DECLINE")
        
    // Create the notification category object
    let meeting_invite: UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: AppDelegate.sMeetingInviteID, actions: [meeting_accept, meeting_tentative, meeting_decline], intentIdentifiers: [], hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: "Preview")
        
    // Register the notification category
    AppDelegate.sUserNotificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([meeting_invite])
}
```

Next, to handle the notification by implementing the [userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) delegate method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive pResponse: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    let user_info: [AnyHashable : Any] = pResponse.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Log(String(format: "user_info = %@", String(describing: user_info)))
       
    completionHandler()
}
```

This method will be invoked after user has tapped a button in the notification. App is placed in background state to process user's action.

Finally, to send the remote notification, I'm doing it the [command line way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools) (Token based approach). But it never works. The test notification, which uses the following command works

> curl -v --header "apns-topic: $TOPIC" --header "apns-push-type: alert" --header "authorization: bearer $AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" --data '{"aps":{"alert":"test"}}' --http2 https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/${DEVICE_TOKEN}

But the modified one for showing an actionable notification doesn't work. There's no notification (even though I did receive the sample test notification). This is my JSON payload,

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "category" : "MEETING_INVITE"
      "alert" : {
         "title" : "Meeting Invite"
         "body" : "Weekly Drag"
      },
   },
   "MEETING_ORGANIZER" : "El Diablo"
}
```

The modified curl command (The above JSON payload is given to the data header of the POST request as a single string) is,

> curl -v --header "apns-topic: $TOPIC" --header "apns-push-type: alert" --header "authorization: bearer $AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" --data '{"aps" : {"category" : "MEETING_INVITE""alert" : {"title" : "Meeting Invite""body" : "Weekly Drag"},},"MEETING_ORGANIZER" : "El Diablo"}' --http2 https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/${DEVICE_TOKEN}

I do get HTTP 200 in the terminal after the command (meaning it reached APNS), but no notification in my phone.

```
% curl -v --header "apns-topic: $TOPIC" --header "apns-push-type: alert" --header "authorization: bearer $AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" --data '{"aps" : {"category" : "MEETING_INVITE""alert" : {"title" : "Meeting Invite""body" : "Weekly Drag"},},"MEETING_ORGANIZER" : "El Diablo"}' --http2 https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/${DEVICE_TOKEN}
....
....
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 1)!
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 1000)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< apns-id: EB0400F7-3CC1-64EF-5DD6-F8158E44BC1D
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.push.apple.com left intact
```

I have verified that the device token is correct and the category key in aps dictionary has the right value i.e MEETING_INVITE.... as registered in code.

What am I missing?

Environment: Xcode 14.2 and iPhone running iOS 16.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json seems to be malformed. Try this:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "category": "MEETING_INVITE",
        "alert": {
            "title": "Meeting Invite",
            "body": "Weekly Drag"
        }
    },
    "MEETING_ORGANIZER": "El Diablo"
}
```

Note the commas at the end of lines.

JSON has some unintuitive rules for commas. When in doubt, use a JSON validation tool, such as https://jsonlint.com

Comment: I thought that was a problem too. But [Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types#2942010) didn't have those commas. Let me check. Nice took btw. Will use that to validate JSON syntaxes :).

Comment: Nope, this new JSON (with those commas) didn't work. Here's the updated curl command using the above JSON - `curl -v --header "apns-topic: $TOPIC" --header "apns-push-type: alert" --header "authorization: bearer $AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" --data '{“aps" : {"category" : "MEETING_INVITE","alert" : {"title" : "Meeting Invite","body" : "Weekly Drag"}},"MEETING_ORGANIZER" : "El Diablo"}' --http2 https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/${DEVICE_TOKEN}`

Comment: the first quotation mark of your data `{“aps"` is weird. Also when I paste this string into the validator and correct the quotation mark I still get an error. There might be some invisible control characters present. What editor and shell are you using?

Comment: that apple doc definitely is wrong :-D

Comment: @NightFuryLxD I just realized there were spaces before the colons that the validator automatically removes. Maybe the apns api doesn't like them either. I've updated my answer

Comment: This is what I did: Copied the sample JSON payload from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types#2942010) to the macOS Notes app, modified it to suit my use case and then removed all newline chars to convert it to a one line string, updated the --data part of the curl request and copied the resulting command to terminal. I'll check the new JSON payload in updated answer (spaces removed before colons) and get back.

Comment: Works!. Commas separating the individual key value pairs of the dictionary and no spaces before the colon..... Thank you :).